# Sort procedure in scheme

Tags: sorting, search, scheme, procedure

How can i write my own **Sort** procedure in scheme which takes in a procedure and sorts it based on the procedure!

If we can,What is the procedure?

*example*- (sort  '(2 4 9 5 3)  >) yields (9 5 4 3 2)

And can anyone suggest a procedure for searching each element of one list in a second list!

Comment: Sure, use quick sort, it's easy to implement in a functional-programming style.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward. You just give the variable to hold the predicate a name and implement the sort strategy of you liking..

```
;; implements a 2 element sort
(define (my-sort2 lst <)
  (let ((fst (car lst)) (snd (cadr lst)))
    (if (< snd fst)
        (list snd fst)
        lst ))) ; already in correct order

(sort '(1 2) >) ; ==> (2 1)
(sort '(1 2) <) ; ==> (1 2)
```

In a slightly more advanced sorting algorithm you need not know both `(< snd fst)` and `(< fst scd)` so that in the case both are these are false you have the third option that they are the same.

Now run along to find [the sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) that you'd like to implement. For few elements even professional libraries use [**Insertion sort**](https://youtu.be/DFG-XuyPYUQ) and often for the larger data sets [**merge sort** or **quick sort**](https://youtu.be/es2T6KY45cA) are good choices.

Many of the sorting algorithms are faster if they are done in fixed sized vectors for longer lists. Thus most libraries actually first makes a mutable vector with the values, does the sort in place, then turns it back into a list. In Scheme implementations like DrRacket you can right click their `sort` and open the defining file to see how it's done. Needless to say its quite advanced in order to do well in most cases.

Comment: @Vishal Notice the procedure used is `cadr`. `(cadr lst)` is the same as `(car (cdr lst))` with fewer steps. Your edit does exactly the same as my original did and thus I rejected it.